# Подменю WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Есть меню, вывел я его на WP, классы допилил нужные, но у одного пункта есть подменю, вопрос как влиять на него и как у этого пункта убрать кликабельность ссылки, дело в том что вообще это делает bootstrap, навешивает data-toggle и ещё атрибуты, а в WP они не добавляются к ссылке

Comment: Советую посмотреть код с помощью F12 и сообщить нам если что-то будет неясно.

Comment: Вы о чем вообще?

Comment: О том что вы нам предлагаете "ванговать", а не решать вопрос, покажите код или что-то что можно изменить/отредактировать, покажите свои успехи по этому поводу, вам иначе никто не будет помогать, никто не хочет делать работу ЗА вас.